# How to find extreme points and directions of $\{x:x_1+2x_2\le 4\}$?

Tags: analysis, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming

> Let $S=\{x:x_1+2x_2\le 4\}$.
>   Find the extreme points and directions of S.
>   Can you represent any point in $S$ as a convex combination of its extreme points
>   plus a nonnegative linear combination of its extreme directions?

**This is what I've done:**

I draw the region S and I saw that there was no extreme points. Then I took a particular point of S and check again that was not an extreme point.

So I could conclude that S has no extreme points. I actually tried to prove formally that S has no extreme points (but I got stuck as usually..)

However the question in the exercise made think that I might be wrong because it mention the existence of extreme points as a convex combination..

---

My question does it really has extreme points?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the Euclidean metric on $S$. Note that for every point of $S$ like $(x_1,x_2)$  such that $x_1+2x_2\le 4$ there exist two points $(x_1+2,x_2-1)$ and $(x_1-2,x_2+1)$ both belonging to $S$ (since $[x_1+2]+2[x_2-1]=x_1+2x_2\le 4$ and $[x_1-2]+2[x_2+1]=x_1+2x_2\le 4$). Since $S$ is convex then whole the line connecting these 2 points belongs to $S$. Now note that $$(x_1,x_2)=\dfrac{1}{2}(x_1-2,x_2+1)+\dfrac{1}{2}(x_1+2,x_2-1)$$which implies that $(x_1,x_2)$ is in the middle of that line and therefore is not an extreme point. Also refer to the following illusion for feasible directions:

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why $(x_1,x_2)$ is in the middle of $\dfrac{1}{2}(x_1-2,x_2+1)+\dfrac{1}{2}(x_1+2,x_2-1)$?

Comment: no, wait. I just saw it.

Comment: Great! Good luck!

Comment: :) sure I need it. Could you give me a hint (s) for the extreme directions of S pls?

Comment: Would you plz define extreme direction of a convex set or a reference to?

Comment: Yes, $d\in S$ is extreme direction if $d=\lambda_1d_1+\lambda_2d_2$ for $\lambda_1,\lambda_2>0,$ then $d_1=\alpha d_2,$ for some $\alpha>0$.

Comment: Where $d_1,d_2$ are directions of $S$.

Comment: The directions are generally the couples like $d=(d_1,d_2)$ such that $d^T\nabla c\le 0$ for boundary points where $c=x_1+2x_2-4$ and all $d_1,d_2\in\Bbb R$ for interior points.

Comment: Really, well in my book says something similar about directions, not the same definition as yours. But I don't see the hint :) or I don't get it.

Comment: I also added an illusion for your better intuition.

Comment: Oh thanks I though you had already gone.